# Return value to click callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have an `<asp:Button name="theButton">` that I handle clicks in using jQuery. I display a custom jQuery UI confirm dialog when the button is pressed.

I've made 2 callbacks; one for the "yes"-click and one for the "no":

```
$('input[name="theButton"]').click(function(){

    myPopUpMethod(function(){

        //user pressed "yes" - perform postback 
        //(return true won't do anything here)

    }, function(){

        //user pressed "no" - don't postback

    });

});
```

If I use a standard `confirm()` I could just do something like:

```
return confirm('are you sure?');
```

But how do I return true or false to the "outer click function" in my first example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the jQuery dialog doesn't block the thread, your click function is always going to return immediately, so you need to do return false; at the end regardless of the dialog result so that the form doesn't get posted.

What I normally do is check for the existence of a data attribute on the button which if present will allow the form to submit, for example:

```
$('input[name="theButton"]').click(function(){
    var $btn = $(this); 
    if($btn.data("dosubmit") == "true")) {
       return true;
    }
    myPopUpMethod(function(){
       $btn.data("dosubmit", "true").trigger("click");
    }, function(){
        // Do Nothing
    });
   return false;
});
```

The first time this is called, the jQuery UI dialog will popup and the method will block the form submit. Once the user clicks "Yes" on the dialog, the data-dosubmit attribute will be set and the button click triggered again. At this stage, the method sees the data-dosubmit attribute and attempts to submit the form.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I do an `e.preventDefault` in order to prevent it. Also, I know that I can trigger the click programatically, but it's a pretty ugly solution, IMO. Isn't there a better way?

Comment: You can use that instead of return false; in my example if you don't want this event to bubble. If you do that you'll need to negate the if() statement and wrap the myPopUpMethod inside.

Comment: You can use Page.GetPostBackEventReference on the server side to get the Javascript call which causes the postback and call this manually from your Javascript method:
`<asp:Button name="theButton" OnClientClick="return false;">
$('input[name="theButton"]').click(function(){
  myPopUpMethod(function(){
  <%=Page.GetPostBackEventReference("theButton")%>
  }, function() { // Do Nothing });
});`

Comment: I think it should be `ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference`. Thanks. Gonna try it out.